# "AdobeGCClient.exe - System Error" at start up

Tags: windows-10

I've been getting an error at boot for the last little while. I'm currently on Windows 10, but this also happened on Windows 8.1

[image: error dialog]

> AdobeGCClient.exe - System Error
>   The program can't start because adobe_caps.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

The thing is, I don't which "program" they want me to reinstall.

I only had a couple of Adobe products on my machine, and I uninstalled them. I've reinstalled Adobe Reader (because I use it once in a while) but I don't use anything else. Certainly not Flash and not their Creative suite. (Alas, I don't remember *exactly* what I uninstalled. Flash, yes. And there was a promotion for Adobe's creative suite, which I didn't want. I'm not sure if there was anything else.)

I have used CCleaner to scan the registry for a leftover key, but that came up empty. A search of the registry with Regedit found nothing for "adobe_caps.dll".

I see the Adobe GC Client in the Startup tab of the Task Manager, but the "Disable" button is, itself, disabled.

Neither Malware Bytes nor Avast turned up anything as far as malware.

There are a number of sites out there that offer downloads of adobe_caps.dll, but where would I put it (even if I trusted any of these sites)?

Any clues? What might I try?

Comment: Don't discard a virus problem either. Did you try downloading the DLL separately and putting it in `C:\Windows\System` and then trying to reboot to see what is exactly trying to do your system at boot time? You can get it from there http://www.dllme.com/dll/files/adobe_caps_dll.html

Comment: DON'T download any dll from anywhere! See my answer below.

Comment: Seems you are not the only one with issues:"The AdobeGCClient.exe is a process that runs as part of the Adobe Software Integrity Service validation testing, which checks for any tampering with Adobe Software program files or improper or invalid license."    https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1948711

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AdobeGCClient is of course a part of the Adobe suite of programs.
In the past years, Adobe products have grown into bloated monsters that are not
completely under control, not even of Adobe.

Probably, when uninstalling Adobe products, some part was left over and now needs some other part that was uninstalled.

The solution is a total cleanup of all Adobe products.
Instead of Adobe Reader, you may then install a free replacement
such as the lean and mean [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/).

Here is how I would go to clean up after Adobe :

1. In Control Panel / Programs and Features, uninstall all Adobe products
   and reboot.
   Or better, use [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) to uninstall and clean after.
2. Delete (or rename) the folder `c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe`.
3. Run CCleaner

Further cleanup entails searching the file-system and the registry for
any mention of the string "Adobe" and deleting them all.
This might not be required, but be very careful if you decide doing that.

If the above message persists after the cleanup, use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)
and drag its bull's-eye icon over the System Error message.
This will tell you which process is issuing this message.
Double-click on the process to see its properties and report on its path
for further cleanup.

Comment: Process Explorer is telling me that csrss.exe is the process which is generating the message.

Comment: If csrss.exe is anywhere other that `C:\Windows\System32`, and if there is more than one such task running, it is some sort of malware. The real csrss.exe is an essential subsystem that must be running at all times and is responsible for console windows and threads. Have you done the cleanup as above?

Comment: I did the cleanup as above. All I had installed was Adobe Reader DC. I deleted the Adobe directory under Program Files, and for good measure removed the Adobe directories from Users/{user}/AppData

Comment: I ran the registry repair in CCleaner which fixed some missing `.dll`s. I checked to see if there was anything Adobe-related in the "Start" options. Unfortunately, it seems there's a bug in the latest CCleaner because it's running out of memory and aborting whenever I do a regular analysis.

Comment: Try the [Eusing Free Registry Cleaner](http://www.eusing.com/free_registry_cleaner/registry_cleaner.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately, Eusing doesn't seem to have found the registry key either. The error is still there.

Comment: For what it's worth, Malware Bytes and Avast both came up empty in a scan for malware.

Comment: Try to search the registry using regedit for the string "AdobeGCClient" (no quotes). Also download [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and do the same inside the Everything tab.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to search also for "Adobe".

Comment: I've scoured the registry for other instances of "Adobe" to no avail.

Comment: Autoruns did, however, find something trying to fire "Adobe Update Manager". I've turned it off and fingers are crossed.

Comment: That seems to have been the issue. I know my way around computer settings; I don't know why this one was so hard to find and didn't come up in my other searches. At the very least, thanks for reminding me about the sysinternals tools.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. I would also verify where is situated this Adobe Update Manager - something more to cleanup.

Comment: Indeed. I'll likely re-install it then uninstall it to see if it cleans up after itself any better.

Comment: I myself avoid Adobe like the plague. Their products take too much liberty with the computer, including bloating the registry with thousands of items. These slow down some operations on the computer, requiring after uninstallation both registry cleanup and registry defragmenting. See [this article](http://windowssecrets.com/top-story/putting-registry-system-cleanup-apps-to-the-test/).